# Show which git tag you are on?

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-tag

I'm having trouble finding out which tag is currently checked out.

When I do:

```
git checkout tag1
git branch
```

I can't seem to find out which tag I'm on. It only logs:

```
* (no branch)
master
```

Is it possible to find out which tags are checked out? In the above example, this would be `tag1`.

Answer (score 467, accepted):

## Edit

[Jakub Narębski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46058/jakub-nar%c4%99bski) has more git-fu. The following much simpler command works perfectly:

```
git describe --tags
```

(Or without the `--tags` if you have checked out an annotated tag. My tag is lightweight, so I need the `--tags`.)

## Original answer

```
git describe --exact-match --tags $(git log -n1 --pretty='%h')
```

Someone with more git-fu may have a more elegant solution...

This leverages the fact that `git-log` reports the log starting from what you've checked out. `%h` prints the abbreviated hash. Then `git describe --exact-match --tags` finds the tag (lightweight or annotated) that exactly matches that commit.

The `$()` syntax above assumes you're using bash or similar.

Comment: Just using `git describe` would show tag name if you are exactly on (annotated) tag, or `<tag>-<n>-g<shortened sha-1>` if not, where `<n>` is number of commits since `<tag>`.

Comment: @Jakub - Thanks. I added `--exact-match` to my answer seconds before your comment. Nice to know that you can remove it and still get good info from fuzzier input.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. Btw, even git-describe --exact-match  (without --tags) works for me.

Comment: Using `git rev-parse HEAD` is a better solution than `git log -n1 --pretty='%h'`... but why you cannot simply write `HEAD` (or nothing, as `git describe` defaults to HEAD)?

Comment: only Guybrush hates porcelain

Comment: When I use this, I get something like `19.04.0-1-g61dcc8f`; I recognize `19.04.0` as the most recent tag, but where is the other stuff coming from?

Comment: This is a linux-only answer.  To do this in Windows, use ``for /F "usebackq delims=" %A in (`git rev-parse HEAD`) do git describe --exact-match --tags %A``, or just use one of the other answers.

Comment: The edited answer is incorrect, it needs the `--exact-match` portion.  Being "on a tag" means the commit you're currently on is what that tag references, not that you have changes since that tag.  Also there's an easier way to reference the current commit:  `git describe --tags --exact-match HEAD` does it on Linux or Windows.

Comment: @user5359531 Official documentation about the tag format in `git describe`: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe#_examples . It's composed by user tag, commit distance and short last commit id.

Answer (score 112):

This worked for me `git describe --tags --abbrev=0`

Edit 2020: As mentioned by some of the comments below, this might, or might not work for you, so be careful!

Comment: Yes. this works even if you are not exactly on that tag! :)

Comment: Uhhh. ... If you checkout the hash three commits after the tag, you are not "on that tag." It tells you the last tag before or at the commit that's checked out. So this is incorrect.

Comment: Works on Windows too :)

Comment: Add `--exact-match` to this answer to only look at the current commit's tag.

Answer (score 102):

Show all tags on current HEAD (or commit)

```
git tag --points-at HEAD
```

Comment: Note that this command does not report an error at the command-line even if the result comes up empty. Bug? It also returns a list if there are multiple tags at that location. It's the best answer  but scripters should proceed with caution keeping these caveats in mind.

Comment: Following @ingyhere's comment. Yes it's good information that it does not have an error, and people need to handle the result accordingly. But I wouldn't call it a bug. For my case, "empty if no tags" is valid. Other cases, someone can save it to a variable then [check if it is empty (link to bash instructions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137431/test-if-a-command-outputs-an-empty-string)

Comment: That meas there are no tags pointing at current HEAD.

Comment: Annoyingly, "git tag" automagically pipes its output through a pager, which resulted in some head scratching when my python script that shelled out to git came up with "(press RETURN)" as a tag.  The fix was: to add "--no-pager" to the git command.

Answer (score 30):

`git describe` is a [*porcelain*](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain) command, which you should avoid:

http://git-blame.blogspot.com/2013/06/checking-current-branch-programatically.html

Instead, I used:

```
git name-rev --tags --name-only $(git rev-parse HEAD)
```

Comment: It is returning "undefined"

Comment: This outputs a trailing `^0` for commits which correspond to tags (eg, for tag `1.0` it outputs `1.0^0`). Is there any way of having Git output only `1.0`, or should I use sed for this?

Comment: @DanielSerodio this worked for me in bash with sed installed: `git name-rev --tags --name-only $(git rev-parse HEAD) | sed 's|\([^\^]*\)\(\^0\)$|\1|g'`

Comment: @DanielSerodio for bare-bones bash this should work: `TAG=$(git name-rev --tags --name-only $(git rev-parse HEAD)) && TAG=${TAG%^0} && echo $TAG`

Comment: Just some conceptual nitpicking: I think you inverted the meanings of porcelain and plumbing. It's ok to use porcelain, it's high level and meant for [normal use](https://schacon.github.io/git/git.html). Plumbing ist internal (as the name suggests) and is only not recommended because the git developers reserve the right to change their arguments and output without warning. So your first suggestion is actually the slightly more appropriate one.

Comment: The linked article says to avoid using "git branch" because it doesn't work for this use case. I can't think of any good reason to avoid using git describe. Like Leo says, "Porcelain" commands are the commands you are generally supposed to use. Avoid the plumbing commands unless you really know what you are doing. "git describe" works great.

Comment: "Porcelain" commands are the ones you should use, not the ones you should avoid. They are the commands whose output is machine readable and will not change in future versions, so can be relied upon in scripts etc. Non porcelain commands tend to produce more human-readable output, but it may change in future versions e.g. to make it more readable, not because something important has actually changed.

Comment: is the `$(git rev-parse HEAD)` actually necessary? it looks like `name-rev` can figure out what `HEAD` is on its own

Comment: According to the main git manpage, `git rev-parse` is also a porcelain command. But as @kbolino notes, it doesn't seem to be necessary here: the `git name-rev` manpage says it can handle ‘any format parsable by `git rev-parse`’.

Answer (score 25):

When you check out a tag, you have what's called a ["detached head"](http://sitaramc.github.com/concepts/detached-head.html). Normally, Git's HEAD commit is a pointer to the branch that you currently have checked out. However, if you check out something other than a local branch (a tag or a remote branch, for example) you have a "detached head" -- you're not really on any branch. You should not make any commits while on a detached head.

It's okay to check out a tag if you don't want to make any edits. If you're just examining the contents of files, or you want to build your project from a tag, it's okay to `git checkout my_tag` and work with the files, *as long as you don't make any commits*. If you want to start modifying files, you should create a branch based on the tag:

```
$ git checkout -b my_tag_branch my_tag
```

will create a new branch called `my_tag_branch` starting from `my_tag`. It's safe to commit changes on this branch.

Comment: Fantastic answer.

Answer (score 12):

`git log --decorate`

This will tell you what refs are pointing to the currently checked out commit.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a fun one for a certain set of use cases. If your repository has versions such as `v1.0.0`, `v1.1.0`, `v1.1.1` etc, and also shorthand versions such as `v1` that point to whatever is the latest `v1.x.x`, the following will give you a reference to the currently-checked-out commit in relation to the most recent fully versioned tag, with fallbacks if that doesn't work:

```bash
git describe --tags --exact-match --match "v*.*.*" \
  || git describe --match "v*.*.*" --tags \
  || git describe --tags \
  || git rev-parse HEAD
```

So let's say you have the following commits:

```
* 4444444 (main, origin/main, tag: v2.0.0, tag: v2.0, tag: v2)
* 3333333
* 2222222 (tag: v1.1.0, tag: v1.1, tag: v1)
* 1111111 (tag: v1.0.0, tag: v1.0)
* 0000000
```

Output of the above command for a few example HEADs:

- `git checkout main` -> `v2.0.0`
- `git checkout 3333333` -> `v1.1.0-1-g3333333`
- `git checkout 2222222` -> `v1.1.0`
- `git checkout v1` -> `v1.1.0`
- `git checkout 0000000` -> `0000000` (full ref)

I've found this useful for GitHub Actions repositories, where you're expected to maintain a verbose set of shorthand version tags.