# Test if a command outputs an empty string

Tags: bash, shell

How can I test if a command outputs an empty string?

Comment: A command does not return a string (it returns a small integer exit code, usually 0 for success and 1 or 2 on failure), but it may *output* some data, to put in a string.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch this is the thing I need.I know command returns exit code.But my commands exit code is always 0.so I need to control the output

Comment: You should read some Bash scripting tutorial http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/

Comment: Joey Hess has a utility `ifne` for this. https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/

Comment: As it sometimes happens, the **[best and most efficient answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39869889/194894) is way down**. You should use `if read -n1 -d '' < <(command); then echo "Command has non empty output"; fi`.

Answer (score 450, accepted):

<sub>Previously, the question asked how to check whether there are files in a directory.  The following code achieves that, but see [rsp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35165216/58635) for a better solution.</sub>

---

### Empty output

Commands don’t *return* values – they output them. You can capture this output by using *[command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution)*; e.g. `$(ls -A)`. You can test for a non-empty string in Bash like this:

```
if [[ $(ls -A) ]]; then
    echo "there are files"
else
    echo "no files found"
fi
```

Note that I've used `-A` rather than `-a`, since it omits the symbolic current (`.`) and parent (`..`) directory entries.

**Note:** As pointed out in the comments, command substitution **doesn't capture trailing newlines**.  Therefore, if the command outputs *only* newlines, the substitution will capture nothing and the test will return false.  While very unlikely, this is possible in the above example, since a single newline is a valid filename!  More information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15184414/58635).

---

### Exit code

If you want to check that the command completed successfully, you can inspect `$?`, which contains the exit code of the last command (zero for success, non-zero for failure). For example:

```
files=$(ls -A)
if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
    echo "Command failed."
elif [[ $files ]]; then
    echo "Files found."
else
    echo "No files found."
fi
```

More info [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html).

Comment: You [can omit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23532711/3075942) `-n`, so it'll be just `if [[ $(ls -A) ]]; then`

Comment: This method gives false for commands that output only newlines.

Comment: If there are files for `$(ls -A)` under if would it be smart to re-run `ls -A`? or on the first call could we save its output and print it instead

Answer (score 132):

## TL;DR

#### `if [[ $(ls -A | head -c1 | wc -c) -ne 0 ]]; then ...; fi`

Thanks to **netj** 
for a suggestion to improve my original:
`if [[ $(ls -A | wc -c) -ne 0 ]]; then ...; fi`

---

This is an old question but I see at least two things that need some improvement or at least some clarification.

### First problem

First problem I see is that most of the examples provided here **simply don't work**. They use the `ls -al` and `ls -Al` commands - both of which output non-empty strings in empty directories. Those examples **always** report that there are files **even when there are none**.

For that reason you should use just `ls -A` - Why would anyone want to use the `-l` switch which means "use a long listing format" when all you want is test if there is any output or not, anyway?

So most of the answers here are simply incorrect.

### Second problem

The second problem is that while **some** answers work fine (those that **don't** use `ls -al` or `ls -Al` but `ls -A` instead) they all do something like this:

1. run a command
2. buffer its entire output in RAM
3. convert the output into a huge single-line string
4. compare that string to an empty string

What I would suggest doing instead would be:

1. run a command
2. count the characters in its output without storing them

   - or even better - count the number of maximally 1 character `using head -c1`
     (thanks to **netj** for posting this idea in the comments below)
3. compare that number with zero

So for example, instead of:

```
if [[ $(ls -A) ]]
```

I would use:

```
if [[ $(ls -A | wc -c) -ne 0 ]]
# or:
if [[ $(ls -A | head -c1 | wc -c) -ne 0 ]]
```

Instead of:

```
if [ -z "$(ls -lA)" ]
```

I would use:

```
if [ $(ls -lA | wc -c) -eq 0 ]
# or:
if [ $(ls -lA | head -c1 | wc -c) -eq 0 ]
```

and so on.

For small outputs it may not be a problem but for larger outputs the difference may be significant:

```
$ time [ -z "$(seq 1 10000000)" ]

real    0m2.703s
user    0m2.485s
sys 0m0.347s
```

Compare it with:

```
$ time [ $(seq 1 10000000 | wc -c) -eq 0 ]

real    0m0.128s
user    0m0.081s
sys 0m0.105s
```

And even better:

```
$ time [ $(seq 1 10000000 | head -c1 | wc -c) -eq 0 ]

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.007s
```

### Full example

Updated example from the answer by Will Vousden:

```
if [[ $(ls -A | wc -c) -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "there are files"
else
    echo "no files found"
fi
```

Updated again after suggestions by **netj**:

```
if [[ $(ls -A | head -c1 | wc -c) -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "there are files"
else
    echo "no files found"
fi
```

Additional update by **jakeonfire**:

`grep` will exit with a failure if there is no match. We can take advantage of this to simplify the syntax slightly:

```
if ls -A | head -c1 | grep -E '.'; then
    echo "there are files"
fi

if ! ls -A | head -c1 | grep -E '.'; then
    echo "no files found"
fi
```

### Discarding whitespace

If the command that you're testing could output some whitespace that you want to treat as an empty string, then instead of:

```
| wc -c
```

you could use:

```
| tr -d ' \n\r\t ' | wc -c
```

or with `head -c1`:

```
| tr -d ' \n\r\t ' | head -c1 | wc -c
```

or something like that.

### Summary

1. First, use a command that **works**.
2. Second, avoid unnecessary storing in RAM and processing of potentially huge data.

The answer didn't specify that the output is always small so a possibility of large output needs to be considered as well.

Comment: `[[ $(... | head -c | wc -c) -gt 0 ]]` or `[[ -n $(... | head -c1) ]]` are better because `wc -c` would have to consume the entire output of the command.

Comment: @netj This is a very good idea. See my updated answer - I added your suggestion. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Any ideas on how to get a hold of the output?

Comment: I think the original (without head) is better in the general case. It's not always a good idea to kill the command as soon as it starts writing output!

Comment: @stk Most programs will exit safely after receiving a kill signal.

Answer (score 55):

```
if [ -z "$(ls -lA)" ]; then
  echo "no files found"
else
  echo "There are files"
fi
```

This will run the command and check whether the returned output (string) has a zero length.
You might want to check the ['test' manual pages](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test) for other flags.

Use the "" around the argument that is being checked, otherwise empty results will result in a syntax error as there is no second argument (to check) given!

Note: that `ls -la` always returns `.` and `..` so using that will not work, see [ls manual pages](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ls). Furthermore, while this might seem convenient and easy, I suppose it will break easily. Writing a small script/application that returns 0 or 1 depending on the result is much more reliable!

Comment: You might prefer to use `$(` instead of backquote, because `$(` nest better

Comment: You are right it is better practice to use them always, although we do not need nesting here.

Answer (score 37):

For those who want an elegant, bash version-independent solution (in fact should work in other modern shells) and those who love to use one-liners for quick tasks. Here we go!

```
ls | grep . && echo 'files found' || echo 'files not found'
```

(note as one of the comments mentioned, `ls -al` and in fact, just `-l` and `-a` will all return something, so in my answer I use simple `ls`

Comment: If you use `grep -q ^` instead, newline characters will also be matched, and grep won't print anything to the standard output.  Furthermore, it will exit as soon as it receives any input, rather than waiting for its input stream to end.

Comment: Should start with `ls -A` if you want to include dot-files (or directories)

Answer (score 24):

[Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html)

#### [6.4 Bash Conditional Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions)

```
-z string
     True if the length of string is zero.

-n string
string
     True if the length of string is non-zero.
```

You can use shorthand version:

```sh
if [[ $(ls -A) ]]; then
  echo "there are files"
else
  echo "no files found"
fi
```

Comment: There is a -z or -n missing in parenthessis [[ ... ]].

Comment: @71GA: Perhaps that is easy to overlook, but if you'll look carefully, you'll see that just `string` is a synonym for `-n string`.

Answer (score 17):

As Jon Lin commented, `ls -al` will always output (for `.` and `..`). You want `ls -Al` to avoid these two directories.

You could for example put the output of the command into a shell variable:

```
v=$(ls -Al)
```

An older, non-nestable, notation is

```
v=`ls -Al`
```

but I prefer the nestable notation `$(` ... `)`

The you can test if that variable is non empty

```
if [ -n "$v" ]; then
    echo there are files
else
    echo no files
fi
```

And you could combine both as `if [ -n "$(ls -Al)" ]; then`

Sometimes, `ls` may be some shell [alias](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html). You might prefer to use `$(/bin/ls -Al)`. See [ls(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) and [hier(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hier.7.html) and [environ(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) and your `~/.bashrc` (if your shell is [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/); my interactive shell is [zsh](https://zsh.org/), defined in `/etc/passwd` - see [passwd(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.1.html) and [chsh(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chsh.1.html)).

Answer (score 8):

I'm guessing you want the output of the `ls -al` command, so in bash, you'd have something like:

```
LS=`ls -la`

if [ -n "$LS" ]; then
  echo "there are files"
else
  echo "no files found"
fi
```

Comment: This doesn't work: the command `ls` is never being executed. You only check whether the _expansion of the variable_ `LS` is non-empty.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf - what makes you think that?  The backtick incantation is admittedly not as pretty or flexible as $( ), but it works ...

Comment: The `-a` switch will never return no content (i.e., it will return content whether there are files or not) since there is always the implicit `.` and `..` directories present.

Answer (score 4):

sometimes "something" may come not to **stdout** but to the **stderr** of the testing application, so here is the fix working more universal way:

```
if [[ $(partprobe ${1} 2>&1 | wc -c) -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "require fixing GPT parititioning"
else
    echo "no GPT fix necessary"
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution for more extreme cases:

```
if [ `command | head -c1 | wc -c` -gt 0 ]; then ...; fi
```

This will work

- for all Bourne shells;
- if the command output is all zeroes;
- efficiently regardless of output size;

however,

- the command or its subprocesses will be killed once anything is output.

Answer (score 2):

All the answers given so far deal with *commands that **terminate** and output a non-empty string.*

Most are broken in the following senses:

- They don't deal properly with commands outputting only newlines;
- starting from Bash≥4.4 most will spam standard error if the command output null bytes (as they use command substitution);
- most will slurp the full output stream, so will wait until the command terminates before answering. Some commands never terminate (try, e.g., `yes`).

So to fix all these issues, and to answer the following question efficiently,

> How can I test if a command outputs an empty string?

you can use:

```
if read -r -n1 -d '' < <(command_here); then
    echo "Command outputs something"
else
    echo "Command doesn't output anything"
fi
```

You may also add some timeout so as to test whether a command outputs a non-empty string within a given time, using `read`'s `-t` option. E.g., for a 2.5 seconds timeout:

```
if read -r -t2.5 -n1 -d '' < <(command_here); then
    echo "Command outputs something"
else
    echo "Command doesn't output anything"
fi
```

---

**Remark.** If you think you need to determine whether a command outputs a non-empty string, you very likely have an XY problem.

Comment: I think this answer is rather under-appreciated. I was performance-testing some of the solutions here using 100 iterations for each of 3 input scenarios (`seq 1 10000000`, `seq 1 20`, and `printf""`). The only matchup this read approach didn't win was with the `-z "$(command)"` approach for an empty input. Even then, it only loses out by around 10-15%. They seem to break even around `seq 1 10`. Regardless, the `-z "$(command)"` approach becomes *so* slow as input size grows that I'd avoid using it for any variable-size input.

Comment: This is the correct answer. However, I wonder if or why `-d ''` is required?

Comment: @Flow: without `-d ''` you'll get a wrong answer if your command only outputs a null byte. Compare `if read -n1 < <(printf '\0'); then echo yes; else echo no; fi` with `if read -n1 -d '' < <(printf '\0'); then echo yes; else echo no; fi`. (I also edited the post to add the `-r` option).

Comment: Thanks, @gniourf_gniourf, that makes sense. FWIW, I as made aware that this approach does not handle `command` returning an non-zero exit status. So if you want to check if the command exited with a non-zero exit status, you also have to inspect `PIPESTATUS` and also exclude exit status 141 (SIGPIPE). The latter assumes that `command` excibits the default signal handling behavior of SIGPIPE. Which is likely, but not granted and as long as `command` does not return some other exit status as 141 on SIGPIPE, it should be sufficiently robust

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative approach that writes the std-out and std-err of some command a temporary file, and then checks to see if that file is empty.  A benefit of this approach is that it captures both outputs, and does not use sub-shells or pipes.  These latter aspects are important because they can interfere with trapping bash exit handling (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221833/pipe-output-and-capture-exit-status-in-bash))

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
some-command  &> "$tmpfile"
if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
    echo "Command failed"
elif [[ -s "$tmpfile" ]]; then
    echo "Command generated output"
else
    echo "Command has no output"
fi
rm -f "$tmpfile"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you want to save the output, if it's non-empty, to pass it to another command.  If so, you could use something like

```
list=`grep -l "MY_DESIRED_STRING" *.log `
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    /bin/rm $list
fi
```

This way, the `rm` command won't hang if the list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned by tripleee in the question comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137431/test-if-a-command-outputs-an-empty-string#comment96407098_12137431) , use [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) `ifne` (if input not empty).

In this case we want `ifne -n` which *negates* the test:

```
ls -A /tmp/empty | ifne -n command-to-run-if-empty-input
```

The advantage of this over many of the another answers when the output of the initial command is non-empty. `ifne` will start writing it to STDOUT straight away, rather than buffering the entire output then writing it later, which is important if the initial output is slowly generated or extremely long and  would overflow the maximum length of a shell variable.

There are a few utils in moreutils that arguably should be in coreutils -- they're worth checking out if you spend a lot of time living in a shell.

In particular interest to the OP may be `dirempty/exists` tool which at the time of writing is still under consideration, and has been for some time (it could probably use a bump).