# Stop and delete Docker container if it's running

Tags: bash, docker, containers

I am looking to pragmatically stop and delete a Docker container if it is running.  This is for a build script.

Take the following example.  How would I stop and delete the Docker container "rabbitmq" as seen under the NAMES column in a bash script?

```
docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                   NAMES
9909a5e2856f        rabbitmq-image   "/docker-entrypoint.s"   11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes       0.0.0.0:5672->5672/tcp, rabbitmq
8990dd1fe503        redis-image      "/entrypoint.sh redis"   6 weeks ago         Up 4 days           0.0.0.0:32770->6379/tcp redis
etc
```

The following command will delete the container and does what I'm looking to do

```
docker stop rabbitmq && docker rm -f rabbitmq
```

However, it's combing it into a script that I would like to know? I think it would look something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ /*docker ps check some value */ ]; then
   docker stop rabbitmq && docker rm -f rabbitmq
fi
```

Answer (score 298, accepted):

As you have probably noticed, `docker stop` as well as `docker rm` exit with a status code indicating failure if the container is not existent or not running. This results in your build failing.

If you can cope with the error messages in your build log you can do this little trick to prevent the shell command of failing:

```
docker stop rabbitmq || true && docker rm rabbitmq || true
```

In the case that one of the docker command fails, `true` is called which always exits with a status code indicating success.

Comment: The error message that container doesn't exist is still returned, but the status code is indicating success. My bamboo pipeline process without failing, so it works for me.

Comment: This will generate `Error response from daemon: no such id: rabbitmq` when container has already been removed.

Comment: @anubhava: Correct. As already mentioned in the answer: The "trick" is to just ignore the return value of the docker commands. If you need a "clean" solution without error messages you need to check if the container is present.

Comment: For me, this command doesn´t work anymore, it used to work but now it doesn´t... Does this happen to anyone else?

Comment: You can run container with `--rm` and just stop with `docker stop container_name || true`. It will remove itself.

Answer (score 81):

I have a similar problem, but didn't like the accepted answer as it suppresses *all* errors from the commands, rather than just the "not found" error.

However, `docker ps -q --filter "name=rabbitmq"` only produces output if a container of that name actually exists, so inspired by [Test if a command outputs an empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137431/test-if-a-command-outputs-an-empty-string/25496589#25496589) I came up with:

```
docker ps -q --filter "name=rabbitmq" | grep -q . && docker stop rabbitmq && docker rm -fv rabbitmq
```

The following command is also useful for testing filter definitions:

```
docker ps -q --filter "name=rabbitmq" | grep -q . && echo Found || echo Not Found
```

---

My actual use case was in defining a pair of Ansible tasks that deleted all currently existing containers (whether running or not) from a list of names generated in an earlier task:

```
- name: Check for containers that actually exist
  shell: 'docker ps -aq --filter "name={{ item }}"'
  with_items:
    - '{{ previous_command.stdout_lines }}'
  register: found_containers

- name: Remove the containers found by the above command
  shell: 'docker stop {{ item.item }} && docker rm -fv {{ item.item }}'
  with_items: '{{ found_containers.results }}'
  when: item.stdout
```

Comment: I find it useful to use `docker ps -aq ...`. The `-a` option means it will also find containers which exist but are not currently running.

Comment: Excellent answer, I just used this in bash script let it restart the docker container if it's already running. Used `ps -aq` as well, as suggested by @PeterBloomfield.

Comment: if the container is not found, `grep -q .` also has a nonzero exist code and thus your entire line. So this still results in an error. Which would force me to append `|| echo 'not found'` or something like this. And at that point there is not much of a difference to the accepted answer

Comment: To avoid the filter affecting the overall command return code, you could refactor it as an if statement: `if docker ps -q --filter "name=rabbitmq" | grep -q .; then docker stop rabbitmq && docker rm -fv rabbitmq; fi`

Comment: I started this with `docker ps -qa --filter` to ensure any crashed containers also show up.

Answer (score 44):

This is my preferred way to stop and remove a docker container.  The piping of true is there to ensure that it always outputs a success.  Without it, any bash scripts would exit and error if the container name did not exist.

```
docker rm -f container_name || true
```

Comment: `docker rm -f container_name &>/dev/null && echo 'Removed old container'`

Comment: [docker container rm | Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_rm/): *Force the removal of a running container (uses SIGKILL)*.

Comment: You can run container with `--rm` and just stop with `docker stop container_name || true`.

Comment: @igor just found this today.  kinda late to the party but running with --rm means you cant take advantage of docker's restart policy.  I user restart=unless-stopped which excludes using --rm.  --rm seems to be a convenience function for dev purposes.  In a deployment, you want docker to try to restart containers after reboot or error conditions

Answer (score 22):

A variant of @ncoghlan's answer:

```bash
# stop runnin container(s)
docker ps -q --filter "name=$name" | xargs -r docker stop
# remove existing container(s)
docker ps -aq --filter "name=$name" | xargs -r docker rm
```

- pipe into `xargs` is an idiomatic way to use output to construct commands
- `xargs -r` avoids running docker commands when no matching container exists
- first `docker ps` finds all matching running containers
- second `docker ps` finds all matching containers, even not running
- separate commands make sure the container is removed even if it isn't running

Answer (score 13):

You can use:

```
app="rabbitmq"
if docker ps | awk -v app="$app" 'NR > 1 && $NF == app{ret=1; exit} END{exit !ret}'; then
  docker stop "$app" && docker rm -f "$app"
fi
```

- `awk` command gets a command line var `app` from BASH's variable `$app`
- `NR>1` skips first header row from `docker ps` command.
- `$(NF) == app` Compare last column `NAMES` is equal to app variable or not

Comment: hi thanks for the answer it does work.  Could you expand on what its doing a little bit.  If I have app=''some-rabbitmq' it does not like the hypen?

Comment: It should work with hyphens, I am adding some explanation in answer.

Comment: too complicated of a solution. Second answer is better

Comment: This is the most complete answer.  the problem with adding ` || true` is that it still exists a bash script with the docker error.

by checking the list of docker containers for the container you are guaranteed to only call stop and rm if it exists, eliminating errors and allowing the script to run all of the container commands needed.

Answer (score 7):

```
# Stop and remove containers with names like "rabbitmq" and "rabbitmq123" if they exist
CONTAINER_NAME="rabbitmq"
OLD="$(docker ps --all --quiet --filter=name="$CONTAINER_NAME")"
if [ -n "$OLD" ]; then
  docker stop $OLD && docker rm $OLD
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

I suggest this incantation in bash:

```
( docker stop $CONTAINER > /dev/null && echo Stopped container $CONTAINER && \
  docker rm $CONTAINER ) 2>/dev/null || true
```

It always exits with 0, doesn't complain if the container is not running, and prints `Stopped container $CONTAINER` if it actually got stopped.

Comment: Clean tear down, that "fails" silently if no container is found, but does not silently `stop`/`rm` the container if it is found.

Answer (score 3):

A general form based on some answers here:

`docker rm -f container_name > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo 'removed container' || echo 'nothing to remove'`

Answer (score 2):

Copy this code in your script.sh if you want `stop` and `remove` all

```
#!/bin/sh
ids=$(docker ps -a -q)
for id in $ids
do
  echo "$id"
  docker stop $id && docker rm $id
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below function. Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/60579344/1554778

```
    function remove_previous_instance(){
        echo "Container name: $1"
        CNAME=$1
        if [ "$(docker ps -qa -f name=$CNAME)" ]; then
            echo ":: Found container - $CNAME"
            if [ "$(docker ps -q -f name=$CNAME)" ]; then
                echo ":: Stopping running container - $CNAME"
                docker stop $CNAME;
            fi
            echo ":: Removing stopped container - $CNAME"
            docker rm $CNAME;
        fi
    }
```

Call it:
`remove_previous_instance "CNAME"`

Answer (score 2):

For stop
for i in $(docker ps | awk '{print $1}) ; do  docker stop "$i"; done

for killing
for i in $(docker ps | awk '{print $1}) ; do  docker rm  "$i"; done

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In the Below scenario:-

1. Docker on windows(wsl2)
2. Jenkins server on the same windows.
3. Using Jenkins pipeline to build and run containers.
4. Using bat script in the pipeline.

In this case, you can use the below command for preventing the build from failing.

```
'docker stop rabbitmq && docker rm rabbitmq || exit 0;'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not delete your stopped containers, another simple way to address this is to rely on `docker ps -a`, which will always return that container id. Then executing `docker stop` on that stopped container will idempotently simply do nothing:

`docker stop $(docker ps -a --filter name= rabbitmq -q )`

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to do this issue

```
docker container ls -al | grep <name> && docker container rm -f <name>
```

Answer (score 0):

In a CI/CD pipeline or something that you don't need the output, the way I use is this:

```
docker rm -f rabbitmq &> /dev/null
```

but as I undertand `&>` is not part of the official POSIX spec so we shoud use:

```
docker rm -f rabbitmq 1> /dev/null 2>&1
```

`-f` (force) in `docker rm -f`:

> Force the removal of a running container (uses SIGKILL)

instead of `docker stop` that sends:

> .. SIGTERM, and after a grace period, SIGKILL

`1> /dev/nul` redirect the output 1 (stdout) to `/dev/null` and `2>&1` redirect the error 2 (stderr) to the same "file". `&` as the firs example redirect both 1 and 2.

To write a real file and append the content use `docker rm -f rabbitmq 1>> docker_rabbitmq.txt 2>&1` or different files `docker rm -f rabbitmq 1>> docker_rabbitmq_success.txt 2>> docker_rabbitmq_error.txt`.

Answer (score -3):

to stop all containers first you have to stop all containers with

```
docker kill $(docker ps -q)
```

and to delete all containers

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

and if you want delete all images this is the command

```
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```

Comment: You cannot do this in the shared environment. Image you have two pipelines running.