# How to execute a Bash command only if a Docker container with a given name does not exist?

Tags: regex, bash, docker

On a Jenkins machine I would like to create a docker container with a specified name only if it does not already exist (in a shell script). I thought I might run the command to create the container regardless and ignore the failure if there was one, but this causes my jenkins job to fail.

Hence, I would like to know how I can check if a docker container exists or not using bash.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

You can check for non-existence of a running container by grepping for a `<name>` and fire it up later on like this:

```
[ ! "$(docker ps -a | grep <name>)" ] && docker run -d --name <name> <image>
```

Better:

Make use of https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/ and check if an exited container blocks, so you can remove it first prior to run the container:

```
if [ ! "$(docker ps -a -q -f name=<name>)" ]; then
    if [ "$(docker ps -aq -f status=exited -f name=<name>)" ]; then
        # cleanup
        docker rm <name>
    fi
    # run your container
    docker run -d --name <name> my-docker-image
fi
```

Comment: Right - you need the `-a` or trying to run an exited container will fail.

Comment: This response does not work if you have two container with similar name. For example: cool.project (container 1) and dashboard.cool.project (container 2)

Comment: @MaximTkach That's why using the second approach is better, where you fully qualify the name of the container in the docker ps commands. But you can also introduce a regex in the grep command to look for whitespace before and after the name. This test is intentionally left to the reader.

Comment: syntax error, should be:
[ ! "$(docker ps | grep <name>)" ] && docker run -d --name <name> <image>

Comment: WiRai's answer is shorter and suffers from no grep-related issues

Comment: As a note, `docker ps` is an alias for `docker container ls`.

Comment: `docker ps -aq -f name=^name$`  will match only the exact name

Answer (score 57):

I suppose

```
docker container inspect <container-name> || docker run...
```

since docker container inspect call will set $? to 1 if container does not exist (cannot inspect) but to 0 if it does exist (this respects stopped containers). So the run command will just be called in case container does not exist as expected.

Comment: I'd even go with `docker container inspect <container-name> > /dev/null 2>&1` to discard both successful and unsuccessful output.

Comment: This is actually the more practical/less error-prone answer; typically it's better to rely on exit codes than text processing since text output is more likely to change over versions.

Answer (score 41):

You can use `filter` and `format` options for `docker ps` command to avoid piping with unix utilities like `grep`, `awk` etc.

```
name='nginx'

[[ $(docker ps --filter "name=^/$name$" --format '{{.Names}}') == $name ]] ||
docker run -d --name mynginx <nginx-image>
```

Comment: This will match on a partial string, but you can get an exact match with `--filter "name=^/$name$"`

Comment: @bcoughlan where is it documented? anubhava: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43202632/895245 had already mentioned it previously, you should like to that.

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心六四事件法轮功 It doesn't seem to be documented in the docker ps documentation. The string is interpreted by Docker as a regex, the '/' character is in the name, although I'm not sure if/why the first `$` is needed.

Comment: @bcoughlan The first `$` is to replace `name` with the value of the shell variable called `name`. The variable is defined just before.  `"name=^/$name$"` is equivalent to `"name=^/${name}$"` (the latter is much more readable IMO).

Answer (score 26):

Just prefix the name with ^/ and suffix with $. It seems that it is a regular expression:

```
CONTAINER_NAME='mycontainername'

CID=$(docker ps -q -f status=running -f name=^/${CONTAINER_NAME}$)
if [ ! "${CID}" ]; then
  echo "Container doesn't exist"
fi
unset CID
```

Answer (score 22):

Even shorter with [docker top](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/top/):

```
docker top <name> || docker run --name <name> <image>
```

`docker top` returns non-zero when there are no containers matching the name running, else it returns the pid, user, running time and command.

Comment: Little note: the question was "if exists" not "if runs"...I used your solution not thinking about that my container can be stopped at that point in time...seems like I have to do inspect even if top is shorter

Answer (score 11):

**Robust grep `^$` without undocumented behavior**

This is the most precise and flexible approach I could find:

```
container_name=mycont
if sudo docker ps -a --format '{{.Names}}' | grep -Eq "^${container_name}\$"; then
  echo exists
else
  echo 'does not exist'
fi
```

Rationale:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38576401/895245 doesn't work if the container name is a substring in another container
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45171589/895245 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/43202632/895245 rely on behaviors for which I could not find the documentation: the exit status of `docker container inspect` and that `-f name` takes regular expressions of some kind.

**Python**

A Python version for convenience since I ended up using it in a project:

```
containers = subprocess.check_output([
        'sudo',
        'docker',
        'ps',
        '-a',
        '--format', '{{.Names}}',
]).decode()
if container_name in containers.split():
    # Exists.
```

Answer (score 9):

This is my solution to check for a running container, stop it, then remove it.

```sh
CNAME=$CONTAINER_NAME-$CODE_VERSION
if [ "$(docker ps -qa -f name=$CNAME)" ]; then
    echo ":: Found container - $CNAME"
    if [ "$(docker ps -q -f name=$CNAME)" ]; then
        echo ":: Stopping running container - $CNAME"
        docker stop $CNAME;
    fi
    echo ":: Removing stopped container - $CNAME"
    docker rm $CNAME;
fi
```

I've had to search this too many times because even the 100+ answer above doesn't actually work. I think the reason is a misunderstanding on docker ps. `docker ps` lists RUNNING containers. `docker ps -q` does the same but the output is striped to include only the container_id. `docker ps -a` lists ALL containers (running or not). `docker ps -qa` then is a simple list of all containers while `docker ps -q` is a simple list of running containers. `docker ps -q -f name=ContainerName` is then a simple list of running containers with the name ContainerName. `docker ps -qa -f` would include exited containers as well so the logic must be to check -a (there, running or not), then without -a to see if it's not only there, but running (and needs to be stopped first).

Comment: These worked perfectly for my use case of: recreating a container every time regardless whether it exists or not.

Answer (score 2):

I use following code to determine if docker container exists:

```
CONTAINER_NAME='my_docker_container'
# Checking if docker container with $CONTAINER_NAME name exists.
COUNT=$(docker ps -a | grep "$CONTAINER_NAME" | wc -l)
if (($COUNT > 0)); then
    echo 'container exists'
fi
```

Comment: Fails for substring match, or if other fields of `ps -a` match, and you don't need `wc`, grep status can be used directly. My version does not suffer from those problems: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50841982/895245

Answer (score 2):

`-a` if you want to list all states (stopped, running etc.)
`-f status=running` (no need if you want to list only running containers)

```
$ docker ps -f name=containerName | grep containerName
```

If there is 1 or more lines status code of command will be 0. If there is no container, grep will be ended with 1 status code. You can handle it by:

Windows

```
$ echo %errorlevel%
```

Linux

```
$ echo $?
```

[image: container is up and running]

[image: when container is stopped]

[image: see the properties of execSync]
Ref: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-bash-exit-status-set-exit-statusin-bash/

Answer (score 1):

```
if [[ $(sudo docker inspect --format . <container-name>) == "." ]]; then
  docker run <container-name>;
fi
```

**Explanation**:

There is a similar response already. The difference here is the `--format .` option (you can also use `-f .`). This removes all the details from the inspect command. Docker uses the [go template format](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/), which in this case means that it will copy to the output anything it does not recognize.

So `-f itIsThere` will return `itIsThere` if a container with that namex exits. If it doesn't, docker will return an error code and message (`Error: No such object: <container-name>`).

I found this one in Jenkins logs.

Answer (score 1):

Here an example of a docker container existence check by exact name:

```sh
(docker ps -a --format {{.Names}} | grep container_name -w) && echo Exists || echo "Doesn't exist"
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/50841982/3124333

Answer (score 1):

to skip Exited container:-

```
CONTAINER_NAME=xyz
if [ ! "$(docker ps -a | grep ${CONTAINER_NAME} | grep -v Exited)" ]; then echo "${CONTAINER_NAME} is not running"; else echo "${CONTAINER_NAME} is running"; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Piggy-backing off of @Fernando César.
This checks for the container id from the given container name and suppresses error output ( `2> /dev/null` ).

```sh
CONTAINER_NAME="awesome-container"

CONTAINER_ID=$(docker inspect --format="{{.Id}}" ${CONTAINER_NAME} 2> /dev/null)
if [[ "${CONTAINER_ID}" ]]; then
  # container found.
else
  # container not found.
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash script I check if container exists by name like this :

```
CONTAINER_NAME="my-container-name"
if ! docker container ls -a | grep -Fq "$CONTAINER_NAME" 1>/dev/null; then
echo "could not found container $CONTAINER_NAME..."
fi
```