# Stop and remove docker container with force ignore

Tags: bash, docker

How can I delete a docker container with force ignore that means if there is no running docker container it should do nothing and if there is a running docker container with the name then it should stop and remove that container.

I am executing the following code to stop and remove the container.

```
docker rm -f CONTAINER_NAME || true
```

If there is a running container then everything works fine, however, if there is no container then the following error is thrown:

```
Error: No such container: CONTAINER_NAME
```

Is there something like *`--force ignore`*? I need this behaviour in order to include it in an automated Makefile.

Comment: How about first checking if such container exists and remove it only if it exists?

Comment: How did you get `CONTAINER_NAME` ? When you used `docker ps`, you might want to combine it with `grep` and `xargs`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this exit code will be 1:

```
docker rm -f CONTAINER_NAME 2> /dev/null
```

this with exit code 0:

```
docker rm -f CONTAINER_NAME 2> /dev/null || true
```

Answer (score 1):

Makefiles have built-in support to ignore errors on a specific command by adding a dash before the command.

```
rmDocker:
    -docker rm -f CONTAINER_NAME
    @echo "Container removed!"
```

You'll still see the error message, but the makefile will ignore the error and proceed anyway.

Output:

```
docker rm -f CONTAINER_NAME
Error: No such container: CONTAINER_NAME
make: [rmDocker] Error 1 (ignored)
Container removed!
```

Reference: [GNU Make Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Errors-in-Recipes)

Answer (score 0):

You can add **OR true** value, as per below:

- One Container

  **docker rm -f CONTAINER_1 || true**
- Multiple Containers

  **(docker rm -f CONTAINER_1 || true) && (docker rm -f CONTAINER_2 || true)**

Answer (score 0):

I prefer

```
docker container inspect CONTAINER_NAME &>/dev/null && docker rm -f CONTAINER_NAME
```

Solution based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45171589/4850949): `docker container inspect` sets return-code to 1 if container does not exist, else sets it to 0, so `docker rm` will be executed, too.

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative you can run container with `docker run --rm`. Container will remove itself once stopped.