# Build error in gitlab CI server (maybe related to git submodules)

Tags: git, gitlab, git-submodules, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have been assigned to a project which uses git submodules. I did a small change in the markdown of the README.md and received the following error:

```
Running on staging.example.com...
Fetching changes...
HEAD is now at 2414dbe test change
From https://gitlab.example.com/external/project-example
   2432dbe..b64b2d0  develop    -> origin/develop
Checking out b452d91 as develop...
$ docker rm -f $CONTAINER_NAME-db
Error response from daemon: No such container: project-example-db
ERROR: Build failed: exit status 1
```

When I check the file named: `.gitlab-ci.yml` I see this code:

```
# ADD   

install:clean:
    stage: prepare
    script:
        - docker rm -f $CONTAINER_NAME-db
        - docker rm -f $CONTAINER_NAME
        - docker rmi $IMAGE_NAME
    allow_failure: true
    tags:
      - staging

# BUILD

prepare:build:
    stage: prepare
    script:
        - git submodule init
        - git submodule update --recursive
        - docker-compose build --no-cache --pull
    tags:
      - staging
```

I'm not sure if my error is due to something missing with the submodules, my .gitmodules file looks like this:

```
[submodule "frontend"]
    path = frontend
    url = git@gitlab.example.com:external/project-example-frontend.git
    branch = v3.1
```

I have the 2 repos (**project-example** & **project-example-frontend**) inside a directory. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to remove the containers *project-example-db* and *project-example* (using `docker rm`) while *project-example-db* doesn't exist. In such case the command returns a non-zero exit status and thus the whole job fails. From the information you provided it's not completely clear how the containers are started. You can:

1. [Check that the containers exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34228864/stop-and-delete-docker-container-if-its-running) and attempt to remove them only if they do.
2. If the containers are started with `docker-compose` (in the `prepare:build` job), you can remove them with `docker-compose down` instead which would do it gracefully and would not fail if the containers are not running.