# Is it possible to delete running container automatically after 1 day?

Tags: shell, docker, dockerfile, boot2docker

I have created my own linux container and its in running state. I want to delete the running container after one day automatically.

Is there anyway to delete the container automatically?

If it's possible, Where do I have to add script/code in my Dockerfile?

Answer (score 3):

There's no built in feature that does this explicitly. However you can hack up a solution in several places.

---

Inside the container, you can have an entrypoint that runs:

```
#!/bin/sh
( sleep 86400 && kill 1 && sleep 10 && kill -9 1 )&
exec "$@"
```

That runs a subshell in the background that will sleep for a day, send a SIGTERM, give the process 10 seconds to gracefully exit, and then send a SIGKILL. The exec at the end then runs your `CMD` as pid 1.

---

You can hijack the healthcheck to kill pid 1 after a day. You can either work with timeouts on the when the healthcheck runs, or look at the process start time with a `ps` command if you need a regular healthcheck for other purposes.

---

Outside of the container, you can run a script, possibly in cron, that checks the output of `docker ps`, greps for "Up .* days", and selectively runs a `docker rm -f` on matching lines. I'd recommend scripting this up using the `--format` option for `docker ps` and using labels on containers to limit which containers you perform this action.

Answer (score 0):

I had this requirement earlier and I used sleep 86400 in script file like

service apache2 start && sleep 86400 in bash script , 
which runs for 1day.

Else you can go through this thread which explained

[stop and delete docker container if its running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34228864/stop-and-delete-docker-container-if-its-running)

Comment: 99,999 seconds is 27.77 hours, you want 86400 seconds for 1 day.

Comment: It was a test environment for me to run for a day so just used 99999, will update answer for exact 1 day