# How to stop a container harmless?

Tags: docker

I use `docker container stop xxx`. It will cause jenkins fail if docker container xxx is not existed.

I want to know if there is an argument to stop a  container without failing.It means when container exists, delete it, otherwise do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this :

```
docker stop CONTAINER_NAME 2> /dev/null || true
```

will always give you exit code 0

Comment: Can you explain it? I can hardly understand it, but it works too. 3Q!!!!!!!

Comment: `2>` redirect the output , so you do not see any output from the command , and if it fail  `|| true` will set the exit code to `0`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below command :

```
docker container ps -all --filter "id=XXXXXX" --format {{.ID}} |xargs --no-run-if-empty docker container stop
```

---

**Explanation** :

`docker container ps -all`: This command will list all the containers.

`docker container ps -all --filter "id=XXXXXX"`: This command will list the container with container id = XXXXXX.

`docker container ps -all --filter "id=XXXXXX" --format {{.ID}}` : This command will only print out the container id.

We will use this container id to pass it to the `xargs` command to run the docker container stop.

`xargs --no-run-if-empty docker container stop`: This command will stop docker container only if command before `"|"` (pipe) is non-empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage in a simple way as mentioned below:

```
docker stop XXXX || true && docker rm XXXX || true
```

This will return true in either case and it will move out with success.

Reference in details at : [stop and delete docker container if its running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34228864/stop-and-delete-docker-container-if-its-running)