# rpm --test never return a non-empty string?

Tags: linux, bash, rpm

I found a great answer on here already ([Test if a command outputs an empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137431/test-if-a-command-outputs-an-empty-string))

I'm trying to apply this to the rpm -e --test  command.  I want to be able to check for dependencies prior to placing a package in a list for removal.   So my simple script looks like this thus far:

```
for PKG in pkg1 pkg2
do
if [[ $(rpm -e --test $PKG) ]]; then
echo "there are dependencies for $PKG"
else
echo "remove $PKG"
fi
done
```

However no matter if a package has a dependency or not I always fall through to the else case.  Any thoughts on how to go about this differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `rpm -e --test` command will return an exit code indicating whether or not the test was successful. Compare this:

```
# rpm -e --test openssh
error: Failed dependencies:
  openssh is needed by (installed) connect-proxy-1.100-12.fc23.x86_64
  openssh = 7.2p2-3.fc23 is needed by (installed) openssh-server-7.2p2-3.fc23.x86_64
  openssh = 7.2p2-3.fc23 is needed by (installed) openssh-clients-7.2p2-3.fc23.x86_64
  openssh = 7.2p2-3.fc23 is needed by (installed) openssh-askpass-7.2p2-3.fc23.x86_64
# echo $?
1
```

Vs:

```
# rpm -e --test figlet
# echo $?
0
```

So you can write:

```
for pkg in pkg1 pkg2; do
  if rpm -e --test $pkg > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "remove package"
  else
    echo "$pkg has dependencies"
  fi
done
```

If possible, it's generally better to use exit codes for determining
the success or failure of a program (because output is often designed
to be human-consumable and can change from one release to the next).

Comment: Thank you!  I actually tried this, but went about it the wrong way.  FYI, you put "rpm -q" rather than "rpm -e" in the if statement.  That threw me off for a while :)