# How to check if pipe content (stdout) is empty in bash

Tags: bash

Some Example:

I've a shellscript where I want to check if a the stdout of a command is empty.
So I can do

```
if [[ $( whateverbin | wc -c) == 0 ]] ; then
  echo no content
fi
```

But is there no direct command, to check this? Something like :

```
if whateverbin | checkifstdinisempty ; then
  echo no content
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [the `-z` conditional expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html) to test if a string is empty:

```
if [[ -z $(ls) ]]; then echo "ls returned nothing"; fi
```

When you run it on an empty result, the branch gets executed:

```
if  [[ -z $(cat non-existing-file) ]]; then echo "there was no result"; fi
```

Comment: the -z could be [omitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137431/test-if-a-command-outputs-an-empty-string/23532711#23532711)

Comment: This doesn't work of the output of the command consists only of ASCII NUL characters and newline characters.  Try `[[ -z $(printf '\n\0\n') ]] && echo EMPTY`.  The code in the question correctly identifies the `printf` output as non-empty.

Answer (score 2):

Just try to read exactly one character; on no input, `read` will fail.

```
if ! whateverbin | IFS= read -n 1; then
    echo "No output"
fi
```

If `read` fails, the entire pipeline fails, and the `!` negates the non-zero exit status so that the entire condition succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[ `echo` ]] && echo output found || echo no output
```

--> no output

```
[[ `echo something` ]] && echo output found || echo no output
```

--> output found

With if :

```
if [ `echo` ] ; then echo ouput found; else echo no output; fi
```

Comment: Plain `echo` does produce output (a single newline character), and the code in the question recognizes that.  This approach can't handle output that consists only of ASCII NUL characters and newline characters.