# Is there any way to check which git tag is deployed or being used?

Tags: git

Locally I can check what all tags are available to use by command git tag, now if I need to know which tag is being used locally, what command I need to use.

Comment: What do you mean by "being used locally"? I think you have access to all synchronized tags, with no difference if created in local or remote.

Comment: Well I meant to say, if I have 2 tags : T1 and T2. I've given these to some other team, they are using either of these tags at their end, Now how do I know if they are using tag T1 or tag T2 ??

Comment: I think your question is not very clear on the first place. please try to explain a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you would like a command that returns the tag name of your currently checked out commit if it is tagged.

You can write this:

```
git tag --list --points-at=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
```

### Explanation:

`git rev-parse HEAD` shows the commit hash of the checked out commit

`git tag --list --points-at={commit-id}` prints the tag pointing at a specific commit.

Note that this command might return nothing, if the currently checked out commit is not tagged

Answer (score 1):

To find out all the tags and branches that refer to the checked-out commit,

```
git show --decorate
```

and you can of course tailor what else it displays with e.g. `-s` and `--oneline` ... there's an endless variety of details you can choose.

If there are multiple tags pointing at the current checkout, you have to consult the reflogs to see which was used to get there. For example, to  find out what reference was used to get the current checkout and what's been done since,

```
git reflog | sed '/checkout: moving from/q'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following referred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33650302/1374947) by  [M K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1734033/m-k)  should give the current tag been checked out:

```
git describe --tags --abbrev=0
```