# Tagging docker image with tag from git repository

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using Gitlab for repository and ci/cd.
Currently trying to set up pipeline that creates a docker image from a build stage.
All examples I have seen have a simple naming of image where e.g. the branch is used(master)

My question is if I want to tag the image based on the current tag in the repository how do I do this?
I am presuming I can use a Gitlab runner variable but do not see one to us

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are a lot of predefined variables in [Gitlab CI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/). I think you are looking for `CI_COMMIT_TAG`.

So you could use it this way:

```
docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_TAG
```

So the image would look like `registry.example.com/group/project:tag`

Comment: note that it will only work if you push a tag, the variable will be empty for subsequent commit

Comment: You can use the "only" checker with variables to skip the build task if it is empty: 

```
  only:
    refs:
      - master
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_TAG
```

Formatting doesn't appear to work in comments. Use your imagination I guess.

Answer (score 5):

As [shell command is not possible yet](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/28314) with variables inside `.gitlab-ci.yml`, you may edit a build script that [get the current tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3404936/2614364) and build the image inside that script

Both file at the root of your project :

`build.sh` :

```bash
#!/bin/sh

IMAGE="$CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_PATH:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME-$(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags)"

docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
docker build --pull -t $IMAGE .
docker push $IMAGE
```

`.gitlab-ci.yml` :

```yaml
image: docker:latest
services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - release

release:
  stage: release
  script:
    - apk update && apk add git
    - ./build.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use this syntax:

```
script:
 - docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_TAG
rules:
 - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG`
```